# When trying to insert data got this error msg Add [name] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Suitspecialist]

Tags: laravel, post, get, laravel-6

Can anyone explain it to me why controller portion throwing error?

Here is my MODEL:

```
class Suitspecialist extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $guard = 'suitspecialist';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

CONTROLLER

This portion throws an error

*Add [name] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [App\Suitspecialist].*

```
protected function createSuitspecialist(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    Suitspecialist::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);
    return redirect()->intended('login/suitspecialist');
}
```

Comment: You might need to clear your caches: Run `composer dump-autoload`, `composer clear-cache` and `php artisan cache:clear`, maybe even a `php artisan route:clear`.

Comment: I tried that and still throws same error

Comment: remove `protected $guard = 'suitspecialist'` try

Comment: Ok, just to make sure: You only have 1 Suitspecialist class in this project? And it is under the App namespace/folder?

Comment: Thanks Rob! I just found out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to fill severeal properties on a model using a method like fill, create or update, you need to specify the fields that can be filled this way. This is call "mass assignment".

This is an Eloquent security implemented to avoid that you store data you don't want to.

In your model, use the `guarded` or `fillable` attributes to specify which properties you want or don't want to register use mass assignment. These properties accepts an array.

Look in the Laravel documentation it is well explained : https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 1):

you couldn't use both the `guarded` and `fillable`. It's better to use just `fillable`.